# Flux and Gauss theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, surfaces

I have a problem; There seems to be something wrong with my understanding of gauss theorem.

Let's say $F = [y ; x^2y; y^2z]$. I want to calculate the flux of $F$ going out of $$D = \{1 \le z \le 2 - x^2 - y^2\}$$

**Method number 1**

LEt's use Gauss theorem.

So $\nabla \cdot F = x^2 + y^2$, and $$\int_{D} x^2 + y^2 = \int_{A} \int_1^{2-x^2-y^2} x^2 + y^2 dz = $$ $$\int_{A} (x^2 + y^2)(1 - x^2 - y^2) dxdy= \int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi} \rho ^3(1-\rho^2)) d\rho d\theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$$

**Method number 2**

LEt's do the explicit calculations.

So let's write $D$ as $r_{up} = [x ; y ; 2 - x^2 - y^2]$ (for the upper part) and $r_{down} = [x ; y; 1]$

This leads to

$$n_{up} = r_x \wedge r_y = [2x ; 2y ; 1]$$
$$n_{down} = r_x \wedge r_y = [0; 0; -1]$$

(I didn't normalize the normal because in the integral I'm going to write directly $dxdy$ without the norm of $n$)

Then $$\int_{D} F \cdot n_{up} = \int_{D} 2xy + 2x^2y^2 + y^2z = \frac{\pi}{8}$$

and $$\int_{A} F \cdot n_{down} = \int_{A} -y^2 = -\frac{\pi}{4}$$ (where A is the unitary circle)

So the two results are different.

Why is this so?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

I edited $n_{down}$, which I belive must be pointing out of $D$ so I changed it in $(0, 0, -1)$. This does not change the fact that the twto methods yields different results, though

Comment: $$\nabla \cdot F \neq x^{2} + y^{2}$$ instead it is $$\nabla \cdot F = x^{2}$$ unless $F=(y,x^{2}y,y^{2}z)$.

Comment: Yes you're right, I edited! I copied $F$ wrong, it is indeed $F = (y, x^2y, y^2z)$

Comment: Can you make your calculation for Gauss' theorem explicit? (The triple integral)

Comment: First method seems wrong... you have to integrate on the 3D domain D. I tried the computation but I got $3\pi/5$ which is anyway different from your second method.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I did explicit the triple integral, plase point out the error.. and there should be an error on the second method as well? I don't understand what's wrong :-/

Comment: Ok, I agree with the first computation...

Comment: In the second computation, shouldn't you normalize $n_{up}$?

Comment: Yes.. but since the flux is $\int F \cdot n d\sigma$, with $d\sigma = |r_x \wedge r_y|dxdy$ and $n = \frac{r_x \wedge r_y}{|r_x \wedge r_y|}$, I (improperly) write $n = r_x \wedge r_y$ and go with it. Should have specified that, though

Comment: @Ant I have posted an answer with what I hope are correct calculations! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the associated form $$G=ydy\wedge dz+x^2ydz\wedge dx+y^2z dx\wedge dy$$ Then $$dG=({\rm div}\; F)dx\wedge dy\wedge dz=(x^2+y^2)dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$$

Now the flat part of the surface, $S_1$; can be parametrized by $(r\cos t,r\sin t,1)$ with $0\leqslant r \leqslant 1$ and $0\leqslant t\leqslant 2\pi$. The upper cap $S_2$ may be parametrized by $(r\cos t,r\sin t ,2-r^2)$ with the very same domain. We see $dz=0$, so you get

$$\int\limits_{{S_1}} G  = \int\limits_0^{2\pi } {\int\limits_0^1 {{r^3}{{\sin }^2}tdrdt} }  = \frac{\pi }{4}$$

On the other hand over the upper cap you have  $$\eqalign{
  & dy = \sin tdr + r\cos tdt  \cr 
  & dx = \cos tdr -  r\sin tdt   \cr 
  & dz =  - 2rdr \cr} $$

You can calculate $$dx\wedge dy=rdr\wedge dt\\ dy\wedge dz=2r^2\cos tdr\wedge dt\\dz\wedge dx=2r^2\sin tdr\wedge dt$$

Then the integral is $$\eqalign{
  & \int_0^1 {\int_0^{2\pi } {\left( {r\sin t\left( {2{r^2}\cos t} \right) + {r^3}{{\cos }^2}t\sin t\left( {2{r^2}\sin t} \right) + {r^2}{{\sin }^2}t\left( {2 - {r^2}} \right)r} \right)dtdr} }  =   \cr 
  & \int_0^1 {\int_0^{2\pi } {\left( {2{r^5}{{\cos }^2}t{{\sin }^2}t + {{\sin }^2}t\left( {2 - {r^2}} \right){r^3}} \right)dtdr} }  =   \cr 
  & \int_0^{2\pi } {\left( {\frac{2}{6}{{\cos }^2}t{{\sin }^2}t + {{\sin }^2}t\frac{1}{3}} \right)dt}  = \frac{2}{6}\frac{\pi }{4} + \frac{\pi }{3} = \frac{\pi }{{12}} + \frac{\pi }{3} =\frac{5\pi}{12}\cr} $$

Then our answers match up $$\frac{5\pi}{12}-\frac{\pi}4=\frac{5\pi}{12}-\frac{3\pi}{12}=\frac{2\pi}{12}=\frac \pi 6$$

Comment: oh thank you :-) It must have been an error in the calculations, since the method appears to be the same I followed! :)

Comment: Can you explain to me what $dx \wedge dy$ means?